# Android Layout Parent Right Visiblitiy display wrong

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_main"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_broadcast"
    android:layout_width="45dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar_main"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

[image]

The correct images are image1 and image2, the actual output is image1 and image3.
When application is loading data, the loading bar will set to `VISIBLE`, and the image displays correctly as image1. When the loading process finishes, the loading bar will set to `GONE` ,it should display image2, however, it displays as image3 which is wrong.
How can I set to correct one (image1 + image2), not (image1 + image 3). I don't know why the smiley will go to left.  Thanks

Comment: because of android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar_main" is gone so ..

Answer (score -1):

use this imageview code

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/iv_broadcast"
     android:layout_width="45dip"
     android:layout_height="45dip"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar_main"
     android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: add both imageview and progressBar in a linear layout(which is a horizontal oriented) so when you set visibility of progressBar gone, imageview auto shift towards right

Answer (score -1):

give android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to both progressbar and imageview.